# POST request oauth2 using doorkeeper

Tags: api, ruby-on-rails-4, oauth-2.0, doorkeeper, oauth2client

I am trying to send a post request to the provider using doorkeeper. I created the application and token, my get request to the api works perfectly:

```
access_token.get("/api/v1/groups")
```

But the post gives me a long error which includes InvalidAuthenticityToken error.

```
access_token.post("/api/v1/groups", params: {group: {title: "Title 1"}})
```

I post the error here [post request error link](https://gist.github.com/simo163/3a85fc37e76b2c704f9e)

This is my controller:

```
module Api
module V1
    class GroupsController < BaseController
        doorkeeper_for :all

        def index
            render json: current_user.groups
        end

        def create
            render json: current_user.groups.create(group_params)
        end

        private
        def group_params
            params.require(:group).permit(:title, :description, :header_image, :privatization, :amount, :currency, :rate, :max_paiment)
        end
    end
end
end
```

Any feedback will be really appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

putting `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` in your controller should solve the problem

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: Thanks gdonato I did not see your post before and actually don't remember how I solved it. I also believe this is the reason, I accept your answer!

Comment: This is because https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper/commit/c1b5c45e2c42c0191ca9f12a2836e31ee1a8de57

Look at the inheritance discussion and you'll understand why.